# HUD layer for Sneaky Input Joystick (cocos2d iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, joystick, hud

I'm using the SneakyInput Joystick to move my sprite, and TMX maps for my game. I added auto-camera-movement to my app, so the hero sprite is always visible. When I go through my map, the joystick goes off the screen (it stays where it's original position is). I made a HUD so that the joystick is always at the same position, and doesn't move along with the map. The joystick shows up on screen fine, but when I drag it it doesn't move my hero.

I've made HUDLayer a CCLayer in GameLayer, which is where I'm making the `moveHero` method. The joystick works, but when I move it across the map, the auto-camera-movement works, but the joysticks stay in there same position, and are out of view pretty soon. I know the problem is that I do `[self setCenter....blah blah blah];` instead of only setting `Level1` as the center. How do I only move the camera for `Level1`, and not `HUDLayer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.qcmat.com/sneakyinput-joystick-dpad-and-buttons-for-cocos2d/) is a link I found on how to use this class. It seems fairly straight forward. I think you want to change the method `- (void)moveHero` to:

```
- (void)moveHero; {
  [self applyJoystick:leftJoystick toNode:hero forTimeDelta:1.0/60.0f]];
}
```

as it seems you already kept a reference to the left Joystick when you initialized the `HUD`.

Ok, if you want to centre the `HUD` layer based on those 2 points (the joystick and the other item), you need only lay them out in a 2D grid, and figure out the centre point from there. I'll assume you are working with an iPhone screen in landscape mode. Then the dimensions are 480x320. The centre of this screen is (240, 160), and so, I would use this centre for my joystick and other `HUD` item. So I would probably set my joystick at (10, 10), and my other item (assume dimensions of this item to be (x, y)) at ((470 - x), 10), which would give the items both a 10 pixel boarder around them.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: If i take out the getChildByTag line I get the undeclared error. Is the two brackets and the semicolon by moveHero a typo?

Comment: No, it's not. The semicolon just makes it easier to copy the method into the .h file really. When you set `leftJoystick = [leftJoy.joystick retain];` above, is `leftJoystick` declared in your .h file?

Comment: This is easy. All you need to do it change how the camera works a bit. I'm assuming you are using a matrix to move the camera. Once you have rendered the map properly, pop the matrix back to the identity matrix, and *THEN* render your hud layer.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean about matrix's...I'm using TMX maps, and a simple method to move the tiles to the center of the screen. I posted the code above.

Comment: Looking at you code, all you have to do it use the bunny's position when rendering map stuff, and then set the camera to the hud's position and render the hud stuff.

Comment: Again - the camera follows the bunny perfectly. But the joysticks get left behind. The HUD has the joysticks in it's layer, and i DO NOT want the HUD to move.

Comment: Exactly. So render the map layer first based on the bunny's position, and then render the HUD layer afterwards based on the Joystick's position. What I'm saying is: Move the camera to the bunny, render the map layer, Move the camera to the HUD, render the Hud layer. Simple as that.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. You want me to move both the map and the joysticks? That's another approach. But when I move the map, I just center it. How would I move the joysticks (to keep them in the bottom left and right corners)?

Comment: Post your render method, and I'll explain.

Comment: That's not where you render the map, that's where you init the map. Don't you have a render method that gets called 60 times per second?

Comment: No...I init the map in the init method. Then I move through it in moveCamera and setCenterOfScreen. I'm not sure what you mean by rendering it. It shows up fine though.

Comment: What engine are you using to make your game?

Comment: Cocos2d...I don't think it's important how I get the map on the screen. What's important is either moving both the HUDLayer and Level1, or only moving Level1.

Comment: So why don't you try both methods, and see which one works? I'm betting that moving the screen to the bunny and then rendering the map layer, and then moving the screen to the HUD and then rendering the HUD layer will work just fine.

Comment: How would I go about moving the screen to the HUD? It's along the bottom edges of the screen (leftJoystick and rightJoystick). It's not the same concept as centering the screen. Please give some code example. Thanks

Comment: Still not understanding why you're talking about the center of the screen, when I don't want it to be at the center of the screen

Comment: I assumed that your bunny is in the centre of the screen when you render the map and everything, and I was trying to be consistent with that, as you probably don't want the Joystick to be rendered in the middle of the screen, but to the bottom left or something. Regardless, just try putting the Joystick at some point in the HUD layer, and render the layer around that point. You can test it out, or figure it out ahead of time, it's up to you.

Comment: No problem! If you have any more troubles, just post a comment here and I'll try to help!